# Picard's theorem proof help(assuming the open set is a ball by a dilation?)

Tags: complex-analysis

Thm: Let $G\subseteq \mathbb{C}$ be open and let $z_0\in G$, and let $F\in \mathcal{H}(G\setminus \{z_0\})$. If $F$ has an essential singularity at $z_0$ then  $F(G\setminus \{z_0\})$ omits at most one point.

In the proof, it is assumed that $F$ is holomorphic in $B(0,e^{2\pi})\setminus \{0\}$ by a dilation. My question is, how would this work? What would this dilation be? Can't seem to figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $B(z_0,r) \subset G$ define $F_1(z)=F(z_0+sz)$ where $0 <s<e^{-2\pi} r$. Then $F_1$ has an essential singularity at $0$ and it is holomorphic on $B(0,e ^{2\pi}) \setminus \{0\}$.